Airflow Error: Airflow exception dag 'test' could not be found
I deployed airflow in EKS. At first I deployed it with sqlite db and sequential executor as configuration and it is working fine. Now i added RDS as database and also Kubernetes executor. When i used that I can see airflow dags in the UI but when i am triggering manually as well they are in queue mode. In pod logs I am having error as Airflow Error: Airflow exception dag 'test' could not be found,either it does not exist or failed to parse. I checked db connectivity it worked fine. But scheduler is not picking up and running it now with k8 executor.  What kind of trouble shooting steps can I further check.

And also I am not using git sync. I am using efs path /airflow/dags. When i ran airflow scheduler command it gave zero tasks at queue with many dags at queue. Not sure why scheduler is not able to pick up and run those dags.  Instead just sending it to queue mode
